# scipy.stats.chisquare isn't giving the results expected from the input data

Tags: python, scipy, chi-squared

I have some data which I want to apply a fit to and then perform a chi-squared test to get the goodness of the fit. It is obvious that the fit I'm applying doesn't fit the data very well (that in of itself isn't a problem, I'm not necessarily expecting it to) but the values scipy.stats.chisquare is returning would suggest an almost perfect fit which is clearly wrong.

What I've done so far is define a function describing the fit I'm applying (a sinusoidal fit), then using scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit this function to my data by getting the fit parameters from popt then using them in the previously defined function to generate a fit.

I'm then taking the measured data and the fitted data and putting them into scipy.stats.chisquare in an attempt to get a fit but that is returning a p-value of 1.0 which cannot be right. My assumption is that there is some problem with using the values generated by scipy.optimize.curve_fit in scipy.stats.chisquare but if that is the case I don't understand why that's a problem or how to work around it.

I have my measured data in two lists which I'm calling "time" and "rate" below

```py
import numpy as np
import math
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statistics import stdev
import scipy


time =[309.6666666666667, 326.3333333333333, 334.6666666666667, 399.9166666666667, 416.5833333333333, 433.25, 449.91666666666663, 466.58333333333337, 483.25, 499.91666666666663,]

rate = [0.298168, 0.29317, 0.306496, 0.249861, 0.241532, 0.241532, 0.206552, 0.249861, 0.253193, 0.239867]

def oscillation(t,A,C):
    return(A*np.cos((2*np.pi*(t-x0))/(t0))+C)
t0 = 365.25
A = 0.35/2
x0 = 152.5
C = 0.475

popt, pcov = curve_fit(oscillation, time, rate, p0=[A,C])


rate_fit = []

for t in time:
    r = oscillation(t, popt[0],popt[1])
    rate_fit.append(r)

print(scipy.stats.chisquare(rate, f_exp=rate_fit))

plt.plot(time,rate, '.')
plt.plot(time,rate_fit,'--')
```

The output of the above is a fit which does look like the best fit to the data when plotted but is clearly not a perfect fit, making the other output of a p value of 0.99999999999458533 which is clearly wrong

Comment: Please test your example before posting, `time` is missing here.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I've changed the code so it is a minimal, complete, verifiable example, albeit with only a section of the data for brevity's sake. As you can see the fit is far from perfect but the claimed p-value is still essentially 1

Comment: @FabienP time (and rate) now  added

Comment: 35 data points is not that much, especially not if you properly round the `time` values to less digits (I doubt the shown precision is validated, given the scatter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only fitting for two parameters, `A` and `C`, thus forcing the phase and period.
If you also fit for the phase and period, you get a much better fit:

[image]

Also in this case, my p-value is 1.0.

The reason why your p-value is 1.0 when `x0` and `t0` are fixed, is that your result is the best fit that can be made *with those values for `x0` and `t0`*. Forcing those values, will very likely produce an overall worse fit. For comparison, with `x0` and `t0` free, I get

```
A = -3.45840427e-02
C = 2.65142203e-01
x0 = 1.88838771e+02
t0 = 2.61112538e+02
```

Compare that to `t0 = 365.25` and `x0 = 152.5`.

Of course, there are (physical) reasons that you want to fix e.g. `t0` to a year, but in such a case, you should worry less that the plot looks bad; your p-value still takes this into account.

The more likely reason, however, is that you are also forgetting the `ddof` parameter in `scipy.stats.chisquare`. It's default is `ddof=0`, which is not what you have: in your case it's `len(rate) - 2`, in my above case, it would be `len(rate) - 4`.
For your fit (`t0` and `x0` fixed), that results in `p = 0.902`. With all parameters free, it results in 0.999887 (i.e., 1 again).

---

Bonus: output when I fix the period `t0` to 365.25:

```
A = -4.05218922e-02
C = 2.74772524e-01
x0 = 8.69008279e+01

p = 0.997
```

and the plotted fit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the in depth comment! It certainly clears some things up with the `ddof`. I still have some questions though and I'm afraid with the full data set I'm using with 35 data points (which I've not included for brevity's sake) the p-value is still exactly 1.0. The first thing I should say is you're right in that there is a physical reason I'm forcing some of the parameters. I'm interested in whether the data fits that particular curve, rather than just looking for the best fit. Continued in a second comment...

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that since [in the reference guide for scipy.stats.chisquare](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) the outcome of the test is defined as "The chi square test tests the null hypothesis that the categorical data has the given frequencies." so what we're seeing is a 'better' fit (p closer to 1) when the two parameters mentioned are fixed which is the opposite of what we expect right?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. What I have is this data that I want to apply a certain, specific fit to then test the goodness of that fit using `chisquare`. My understanding is the p-value (as defined by scipy.stats.chisquare) would be 1.0 for a perfect fit and 0 for a totally imperfect. Visually and from experience I'd expect a p-value between 0.1 and 0.7 (being generous) so very close or equal to 1 is unexpected.

Comment: in response to your other comment re the numbers of data, that's part of my confusion, surely the relative lack of data should give me a _lower_ p-value?

Comment: Aha! I hadn't actually added the change to `ddof` like I thought I had. I think it now works as intended. At any rate I'm now getting much more sensible results. Thank you for your help!